# How to Pass a view from controller?

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring MVC. And I am trying to work with multiple views. When I use a single view and a single controller it works perfectly. But when I try to open a view from another view, I am getting HTTP 404 error (The requested resource is not found)

[Project Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cEds.png)

As in the picture, I am having index.jsp as my home page view. From this page, I need to navigate another page(viewpage1.jsp) which is inside the WEB-INF/jsp directory. When I do so, I get HTTP 404 not found error.

`HelloController.java`

```
package com.springwebproject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class HelloController
{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String display()
    {
       return "viewpage1";
    }
}
```

`index.jsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<h1>Home Page</h1>
<a href="viewpage1">Go to Next View</a>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringWebProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringWebProject</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringWebProject</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/viewpage1.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`spring-servlet.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">  
  
    <!-- Provide support for component scanning -->  
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springwebproject" />  
  
    <!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->  
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
          
     </bean>  
</beans>
```

`viewpage1.jsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<h1>First View Page after Home page</h1>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'open a view from another view'? Show some code.

Comment: Please explain properly by writing some part of your code, and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: How about changing the href to `"/viewpage1"`?

Comment: @k-wasilewski I tried that one too. It didn't work. But If I give it as viewpage1.jsp, it works

Answer (score 0):

Add this bean to your configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/views/"); // locate your directory with *.jsp files here
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

Comment: But I am having another one doubt. Do I have to add jstl.jar file under /WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Does your `index.html` work? I think in SpringMVC the views ought to be placed in `/webapp`...

Comment: I think `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` is enough.

Comment: Now, I kept all the views inside webapp folder. In index.jsp if i give the link as viewpage1.jsp, it works but <a href="viewpage1"> not works

Comment: Post your Configuration

Comment: configuration means, are you asking dispatcher servlet configuration

Comment: No, I mean `WebMvcConfigurer`. Also, are you using a `spring-webmvc` dependency?

Answer (score 0):

as you have given the mapping as "/hello" to view viewpage1, you have to change your href like this:

```
<a href="/hello">Go to Next View</a>
```

Let me know, if this helps.